# pcapy.findalldevs() No valid interfaces to open

Tags: python, linux, pcap, fuzzing

I am trying to run Sulley's (the fuzzer) "network_monitor.py" on an Ubuntu vm. Everytime I do, I get the following error.

`pcapy.PcapError: No valid interfaces to open`

I believe that this has little to do with the code I am running it in, because when I run

```
python
>>> import pcapy
>>> devices = pcapy.findalldevs()
```

I get the same error

Any hints on what's going on would be amazing. Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what you mean by "an Ubuntu vm"?

Comment: Are you running as root ? Only root will have enough permissions to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it with `sudo`.

Pcapy, AFAIK, needs special rights to access interfaces.

```
mycode.py:
    import pcapy
    devices = pcapy.findalldevs()

sudo python mycode.py
```

Comment: Worked, so simple thanks so much I really appreciate it. Do you happen to know why this requires root access?

Comment: You just can't manipulate network interfaces as usual user, it is acceptable only under root(suder). It will be embarrassing if some user will sniff your packages if both of use are located on same server, don't it?