# pcapy.findalldevs() No valid interfaces to open in Windows

Tags: python, pcap, fuzzing

A simiar question has been asked in Linux and been solved:
[pcapy.findalldevs() No valid interfaces to open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270255/pcapy-findalldevs-no-valid-interfaces-to-open)

But I have this problem when I tried to run `python network_monitor.py` in Windows. Do I need to get the special rights in Windows? If so how to I get it as we use `sudo` in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking the command prompt icon in the start menu or equivalent Windows 10 menu and clicking "Run as Administrator." Then run network_monitor.py from that prompt.